# WebRequest.WebResponse unavailable in universal Windows 8.1/Windows Phone 8.1 C# app

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to do a very simple HTTP request on a URL in order to use the returned data. Everything I've done before and everything I'm reading on MSDN indicates that this should work:

```
string url = "http://www.abettergeek.com/misc/hovservice.php";
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

However, **GetResponse()** apparently doesn't exist for **HttpWebRequest**, even though it seems like it should.

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:

I figured out how to use HttpClient correctly. I was trying to assign the result of the HttpClient stream to a variable, which wasn't working the way I wanted it to.

I ended up using the following:

```
Uri north = new Uri("http://www.abettergeek.com/misc/hovservice.php");
HttpClient northc = new HttpClient();
string northr = await northc.GetStringAsync(north);
```

Comment: Use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx for Windows 8.1 apps.

Comment: Synchronous IO is not supported. You should instead mark your method async and use the async counterpart of the GetResponse... GetResponseAsync ... see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.net.httpwebrequest_methods%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: I'm getting really confused about how these methods actually work. I can't figure out GetResponseASync at all, and HttpClient.GetStringAsync returns null.

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HttpClient-sample-55700664 take a look at this sample